# How to filter a table based on email address suffix

Tags: r, regex, filter, tidyverse, spam

I have a table of over 100K names and addresses . I would like to filter the table to keep only those emails I think are not spam.

i have for example addresses as such

```
XXX@123.com
2wsc@111.com
13625651286@139.com
```

I would like to filter now those addresses that have only digit before the `@` symbol as well as those emails which have only digit after the `@`, but before the suffix `.com`.

I know I can extract them using `str_split` and `grepl`, but I can't fit them into a `filter` query to remove them from the table.

```
pattern <- "fuxianan1@163.com"
str_split(pattern, '@') # this will split the address based on the sumbol

str_split(string = str_split(pattern, '@')[[1]][2], pattern = "\\.") # this will split the doamin name based on the dot separating the suffix from the numbers.

as.numeric(str_split(string = str_split(pattern, '@')[[1]][2], pattern = "\\.")[[1]][1]) # This for example will check if the string extracted above contains only numbers, if not it will return NA
```

But how do I combine this in a `tidyverse` query?

thanks

P.S.
I know this is a farfetched question, but is there some kind a spam filter for email address one can use within R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this pattern should help you identify the spam email as per your condition.

```
^\\d+@|@\\d+\\.com
```

To use it in `filter` you may use `grepl` or `str_detect` from `stringr`.

```
data %>% filter(grepl('^\\d+@|@\\d+\\.com', email))
```

To get rows which are not spam negate the condition using `!`.

```
data %>% filter(!grepl('^\\d+@|@\\d+\\.com', email))
```

---

Example :

```
x <- c('XXX@123.com', '2wsc@111.com', '13625651286@139.com', 'abc@gmail.com')
grepl('^\\d+@|@\\d+\\.com', x)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Note that `(\\d+)@` has the same effect as `(\\d)@` because there is nothing preceeding it in the RegEx. The `+` within `@\\d+\\.com` cannot be removed as there is something (i.e. the `@`) before the `\\d+`.

Comment: thanks, this is truly simple, but is there a way to test, if there are ONLY digits at the start of the address?

Comment: if you reduce the regex to `^\\d+@` then it would only filter for exclusive digits before `@`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather simple solution and I think there might be a cleaner way without creating all these extra columns:

```
adress <- c("12w@123.com","12@world.com","1World@1world.com")

adf <- as.data.frame(adress)

adf[c("Before","After")] <- str_split_fixed(adf$adress, '@',2) # this will split the address before @

adf[c("After2","com")] <- str_split_fixed(adf$After,"\\.",2) # this will split the remaining @ 

library(dplyr)
adf <- adf %>% filter(grepl('[a-zA-Z]', Before)) 

adf <- adf %>% filter(grepl('[a-zA-Z]', adf$After2))

adf$adress

[1] "1World@1world.com"
```